# Почему пропускает конструкцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Запускаю в командной строке. Считывает а и б, а вот если ввожу Y + Enter или N + Enter - краш.

```
a = int(input("Введите начало счёта: "))
b = int(input("Введите конец счёта: "))
interval = input("Хотите ли Вы ввести интервал (Y/N): ")
if interval == Y:
    с = int(input("Введите интервал между называемыми целыми числами: "))
input()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if interval == Y:
> ```

```
if interval == 'Y':
```

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо Вам. Оказывается, комп думал, что я имею ввиду переменную Y, а не строку "Y" :)

Comment: Если проблема решена, прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: Хорошо, но мне пишет, что только через 6 минут смогу, обязательно поставлю

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk Комп не думал, он выполнял то, что написано. И кстати сообщал после краша в чем именно проблема. Нужно просто читать сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: @Эникейщик извиняюсь за "некорректно подобное выражение", я знаю, что комп не думает, а выполняет то, что ему "приказывает" код, но решил применить такого рода метафору. А что насчёт краша? Где я могу посмотреть сведения об ошибках?

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk да там же, где выводится текст вашей программы. В вашем случае было написано что-то вроде variable referenced before assignment и показана строчка в коде, где возникла ошибка.

Comment: @IlyaSidorchuk Ваш код должен вывести `Traceback` и следующее исключение (ошибку): `NameError: name 'Y' is not defined`, что в переводе означает: `ОшибкаИмени: имя 'Y' не определено`.